# Gatsby - running in it's own folder on an existing site

Tags: gatsby

Can Gatsby be configured to run inside its own folder on an existing site and pull page data from a folder outside that Gatsby folder?

For example as a help and support area on an existing application where the existing code base includes `readme.md` files that would be the content for the static help and support website.

Answer (score 1):

You can place gatsby in a subdomain such as: https://gatsby.your-domain.org . Gatsby will do its thing in this subdomain. Take a look at [path-prefixing](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/).

You can define your page data from outside the Gatsby folder as a datasource. You need to expose your readme.md files in a way. Here is the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/content-and-data/) that can help you with that.

Some internals that make Gatsby great won't work in connection with your main site. [Gatsby Link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#reminder-use-link-only-for-internal-links) comes to mind.